# Why the perf4j graphs are not generated?

Tags: java, logging, logback, perf4j

I've integrated Perf4j in a standalone application. I'm using SLF4J / logback as the logging system.

The statistics are correctly generated in the perfs.log, but nothing is generated in the graphs.log file.

Here is my logback.xml configuration file:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="graphs_file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>logs/graphs.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>logs/graphs.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="graph_mean" class="org.perf4j.logback.GraphingStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="GraphType" value="Mean"/>
        <param name="TagNamesToGraph" value="g2p-load,p2g-load,phonetize-request,graphetize-request,full-request"/>
        <appender-ref ref="graphs_file"/>
    </appender>

    <appender name="perf_file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>logs/perfs.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%date %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} [%file:%line] %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>logs/perfs.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="log_file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>logs/veriname.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>logs/veriname.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="coalescer" class="org.perf4j.logback.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="TimeSlice" value="60000"/>

        <appender-ref ref="graph_mean"/>

        <appender-ref ref="perf_file"/>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.perf4j.TimingLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="coalescer"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="log_file" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

In the code, I'm using:

```
StopWatch watch = new Slf4JStopWatch("phonetize-request");
```

The weird thing is that it works well for the aggregation in the perfs.log file but nothing happens in the graphs.log.

What am I doing wrong ?